# Download and save file from Amazon S3 with Unity C#

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am following Amazon's tutorial on S3 but I cannot download file and save it to Streaming Resources. Instead I am downloading file content.

```
ResultText.text = string.Format("fetching {0} from bucket {1}", SampleFileName, S3BucketName);
Client.GetObjectAsync(S3BucketName, SampleFileName, (responseObj) =>
{
    string data = null;
    var response = responseObj.Response;
    if (response.ResponseStream != null)
    {
        using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(response.ResponseStream))
        {
            data = reader.ReadToEnd();
        }

        ResultText.text += "\n";
        ResultText.text += data;
    }
});
```

I understand that I should convert the `response.ResponseStream` into File but I tried many different solutions and I could not make it working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I understand that I should convert the response.ResponseStream into File but ....

You do not convert it into a file you read from it and write the content to a file. There are plenty of built in methods that help with this but the steps are simple. Open/Create a file stream and then write from the response stream to the file stream.

```
if (response.ResponseStream != null)
{
    using (var fs = System.IO.File.Create(@"c:\some-folder\file-name.ext"))
    {
        byte[] buffer = new byte[81920];
        int count;
        while ((count = response.ResponseStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) != 0)
            fs.Write(buffer, 0, count);
        fs.Flush();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, however I am getting follwoing error msg: `Type `System.IO.Stream' does not contain a definition for `CopyTo' and no extension method `CopyTo' of type `System.IO.Stream' could be found. Are you missing an assembly reference?`

Comment: @Lenny - you might be using an older version of .net or the .net core. The CopyTo method is just this (see update).

Comment: thank you very much! Works like a charm! Instead of `destination` I had to put `response.ResponseStream`